# PHP, XML How to get attributes?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to return the values of the `SECTION` attribute of the `INTRO` tags from the following xml:

Sample of myxml.xml:

```
<INTRO SECTION="ONE">
  <TEXT>Hello</TEXT>
</INTRO>
<INTRO SECTION="TWO">
  <TEXT>Goodbye</TEXT>
</INTRO>
```

My PHP:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('myxml.xml');
$intros = $doc->getElementsByTagName("INTRO");

foreach( $intros as $intro ) {
echo $intro ->get_attribute('SECTION');
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Call to undefined method DOMElement::get_attribute()

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Kind regards to any responders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DOMElement::getAttribute()`](http://php.net/domelement.getattribute)

```
$intro ->getAttribute('SECTION');
```

Comment: Thanks @KingCrunch... getAttribute not get_attribute... I was getting confused because of the following link... http://php.net/manual/en/function.domelement-get-attribute.php... thanks.

Comment: `DOM` and `DOM XML (PHP4)` are two separate extensions. See http://php.net/refs.xml

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
   ....
  $attr=$intro->attributes();
  echo $attr['SECTION'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am getting the following error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::attributes() .... Do you think there is something incorrectly set up in my PHP?

Comment: 5.3... however KingCrunch has answered it... should be getAttribute not get_attribute...I was getting confused because of the following link... php.net/manual/en/function.domelement-get-attribute.php... Thanks for your help though, much appreciated... J

Comment: KingCrunch is right as you can see in your link, it says use getAttribute for php 5 otherwise I use ->attributes() recently and it works fine. it give you a array with all attributes then you only have to get what you want $attr['attribute_name']

Comment: @Xenione You are talking about SimpleXML (http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes), one more XML extension. That's slightly independent from the PHP-version ... See http://php.net/refs.xml too

Comment: ok, of course I forget that you have to use $xml = simplexml_load_file('myxml.xml') before; I recommmend that, the file become a php object so it's really easy to use.

Comment: @Xenione It becomes slightly confusing now ;) With the `DOM`-extension uses objects too (as you can see above `$intro->getAttributes()`). Even the `XMLReader`-extension use classes. At the end everone of this is able to read XML-files. Some are simpler, but less powerful, the other one is faster, but more complicated (and so on). Important is only, that they are all different extension.

Comment: it's not confuse just two ways to do the same, if you only want to read the xml and get the attributes and values I recomend simpleXML, if you want to read and edit the DOM(apend some node, change the DOM structure) you have to use DOM-extension, if you want to read the xml without memory just reading the file use XMLReader.

Comment: @Xenione The part, that confused me, was "the file become a php object", whats the same, when using `DOM` (and therefore is not a difference). Sorry for this ... ehm, confusion ^^

Comment: you re right all become an object, after looking trough I realize that it's  more or less the same, with simpleXML is a little bit more simple to manipulate XML files but less powerfull.